# A function returning only one index instead of two or more | C++

Tags: c++

inside Caleb Curry's C++ course I have stumbled upon a piece of code about classes with a function returning an index if found two objects with the same data members. Here's the function:

```
int indexuser(std::vector<User> &users, User user)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
        if(users[i].fname == user.fname && users[i].lname == user.lname)
        {
            return i;
            std::cout << "\n";
            
        }
    }
    users.push_back(user);
    return users.size()-1;
}
```

It seems to me that the function should return two indexes or more if found matching users, cause no matter what it should always return the last index of a vector. However the function returns only the first one it found. Can someone explain to me why does this happen? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `return` ends the function. It doesn't "stack" things to return.

Comment: And so `std::cout << "\n";` is unreachable code.

Comment: What have you learned about `return`? What happens after `return i;`? Is `std::cout << '\n';` ever executed?

Comment: The code checks if there is a user in the vector with a given first and last name and returns the index if found. There is no check for two users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function checks if user(of type User) is present in the vector users. If found it will return index of the user found in vector and if not found, it will insert the user (using`users.push_back(user)`) in the vector and return its index (which will be `users.size()-1`).
And whenever (any) function finds return statement it returns to its calling statement terminating everything else.

Answer (score 1):

If the function meets the `return` statement, it immediately returns to the code that called that function.
Subsequent code will not run.
In other words, the `return` command may exist several times in function, but at the first time the program meets `return` the function execution is finished, and only one value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ normal functions can return only 1 value. This value can be of any available type: an integer, its own structure or a standard container, or any other, but this value will be the only one. So the functions are simply executed until you execute the first operand return. As soon as they meet return, they return the corresponding value and complete their execution. Functions are absolutely indifferent to what happens after the first return, because they complete their execution. So in the function described below, only the number 42 will be returned. Moreover, the variable **a** will not be equal to the number 5, because the function ended before assign operator

```
int func(int &a)
{
    return 42;
    a = 5;
    return 51;
    return 1;
}
```